# Matplotlib Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have the following code that works to produce two charts, but I would like to use subplots to put them side by side. How can I do that?

```
p1 = df1.var1.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
p2 = df2.var2.value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()

p2.plot(kind='barh').invert_yaxis()
plt.xlim(0, 0.5)
plt.title('my title1')
plt.xlabel('% of Users')
plt.ylabel('my ylabel 1')
plt.show()

p1.plot(kind='barh').invert_yaxis()
plt.xlim(0, 0.5)
plt.title('my title 2')
plt.xlabel('% of Users')
plt.ylabel('my ylabel 2')
plt.show()
```

I started using add_subplot with the following code, but not sure how I can add the the above code into fig. Any help would be appreciated!

```
fig = plt.figure()

fig1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
fig2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a figure with two subplots

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
```

and plot in the according axes objects, e.g.,

```
p2.plot(kind='barh', ax=axs[0]).invert_yaxis()
axs[0].set_xlim(0, 0.5)
axs[0].set_title('my title1')
axs[0].set_xlabel('% of Users')
axs[0].set_ylabel('my ylabel 1')
```

and accordingly `axs[1]` for `p1`.

Note that the `axes` object updates, e.g., the label by the method `ax.set_xlabel` instead of `plt.xlabel`. You can find more information here: https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow up question, is there a quick way to add label to the chart (the % each bar represents)?

Comment: I have modified the original post to also include the labels and title. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was for the chart to show the values each bar represents. Right now there are just horizontal bars but it’s a bit hard to tell the value of each bar. For example, if the bar represents 75%, can we show the 75% in the chart easily? Does it make sense?

Comment: There is the possibility to [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) features. Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: hmm not really. just so the bars can automatically show the values they represent